# Way older dates on document recovery window

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

One of my colleague recently discovered an issue where as she sees dates that are way past (like in the 1600's) than 20th century. This is when she opens a document that was like crashed and shows the document recovery. Below is a screen of what she has got;

[image]

Was trying to figure out searching in Google but nothing came up or maybe I'm searching incorrectly. If anyone has any idea as to what this is or whether we can get this fixed, it will be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document has lost the data for when it was created.
The date/time you are being displayed there is the ["Win32 Epoch"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090306-00/?p=18913/).

Because it has lost the data for the actual date/time, it is using the minimum value possible instead. It is probably just a technical glitch, the date/time is most probably `NULL`, the program does not allow nulls so substitutes 0 instead, 0 converted to the date/time format you are seeing equals the first of January 1601 at 5:00AM.

As a side note, it also counts up in millisecond intervals, so a value of `1` would equal to `1/1/1601 5:00 + 100ms`, a value of 2 would equal `1/1/1601 5:00 + 200ms`, to store whatever date you would want in this format you just need to know the number of 100 millisecond intervals since the epoch.

Comment: Likely story!  Obviously, those files were created moments apart on the same day on a REALLY, REALLY old computer.

Comment: +1 to this. I was having a bit of argument lately with myself after posting this. Didn't know this will be linked to the **epoch** though. BTW, thank you for the detailed information.